# Specific CSS Values

Tags: css

I have dynamically generated code like the following:

```
<div class="message-error error">The Message field is required.</div>
<div class="email-error error">The Email field is required.</div>
```

Is there anyway that I could write my css with out having to state every field name before the `-error error`?

Comment: depends entirely what message-error and email-error css values are...

Comment: What's the difference between `message-error` and `email-error`? Please post the CSS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When class names are separated by spaces, it means that styles from both classes will be applied to that element.

If you were to have the following CSS:

```
.error {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.message-error {
    color: blue;
}

.email-error {
    color: green;
}
```

Then both elements would be bold, but the colors would each be applied to only one element from your sample.

Comment: So whatever you want all the errors to have in common would go under the `.error` class.

Answer (score 0):

the `div.error` selector should be what you need.

Comment: Why was this downvoted?  This is the right answer.  The `error` class is on both divs, so selecting on that should cover both.

Comment: @Jacob: Not necessarily--this wouldn't be the case if `message-error` and `email-error` defined different styles, like I asked about in the comments.